# How do I get this type of moving background (see picture)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

[image: the offliberty website background]

If you go to the [offliberty website](http://offliberty.com), one of their background designs is the one in the picture above (it moves). I was wondering how I could get a background like this. I was reading through the source code, and I can't seem to figure out where this one comes from. It is a specific type of file (i.e., a gif) that is being used as a background?

I wanted to use something similar (maybe floating code), but have no idea as to how to accomplish such.

Comment: I'd use floating code too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are using a gif, and they are tiling it across the background. Here is a link to the gif http://offliberty.com/img/bg/gas.gif
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is so simple, take a look at the css file at the top of the code source:

```
..
..
..
.wrapper6 {
    background: #fff url('/img/bg/gas.gif') repeat fixed;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 100 % ;
}
..
..
..
```

The picture file (an animated gif) is located here:

```
http://offliberty.com/img/bg/gas.gif
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wish to know?

http://offliberty.com/img/bg/gas.gif

That's just a gif image.